# Spa/pool plumbing leaking without water flowing?

Tags: plumbing, pool

I installed a electric tankless heater for our spillover spa and discovered a couple leaks on the 2in PVC piping going through the heater even though the valve is not oriented that way. The leaks happen when I run a 1.5 HP pentair superflo vs pump at medium speed.
[image]

Both of the leaks are happening at threaded connections. The first is on the heater's outlet stainless steel PVC adapter, and the other is at the inlet of the check valve. For the check valve I bought Home Depot's Everbilt 2 in. FIP x FIP PVC Check Valve. It says it has a maximum PSI of 200. To seal the threaded connections, I applied T Plus 2 pipe dope generously to all threads.

What confuses me is why it's leaking at all considering the water shouldn't be flowing through the heater since the three-way valve is supposed to divert to the pool. What would the likely problem be and how could I fix it?

Here are some close ups of the leaking locations:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Valves only stop water from flowing, they do not remove water from the pipes.  Most pipes do leak better when water is under pressure, but sitting water will leak also.

Comment: The leak stops when the pump is off, so I think the seal is good enough to prevent sitting water from leaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double-check the way your 3-way valve works. My 3-way valve (Jandy) directs flow *the opposite* way from the way the handle points. In other words, I think you have the valve set for flow through the heater in the picture.

Another thing: you say it is leaking at "the heater's outlet", but the circle in your picture is the **inlet** to the heater.

It is not uncommon for threaded fittings to leak when not thoroughly tightened (not saying that's the case here, just saying...) Also, schedule-40 fittings like those you used are not very heat-resistant. I would have used schedule-80 threaded adapters at the pump discharge and at the heater inlet and outlet ( I know this doesn't account for the leak at the check valve, but hey coincidences happen).